# R matching different number of words

Tags: r, regex

I thought my RegEx skills are good enough but now I'm sitting here having no idea how to solve my problem.

First I have a text like:

`text <- "This DEV-1231 story is about a man. He DEV-1232 is from DEV-1233 the USA. He is a university professor. He goes DEV-1234 to Nepal. He DEV-1235 climbs a mountain. The mountain is covered in ice. There is a hole in the ice. It is 22 metres deep. The man falls in it. DEV-1236 He doesn’t DEV-1237 go all the way down. He stops somewhere in the hole. He cannot move. His arm and five ribs are broken."`

With some special unique developper IDs kind of:

`dev_id <- "DEV-123[0-9]"`

It's no problem to extract them with `str_extract_all` and `unlist` them afterwards.

But I want to extract the following 30 chars or 5 words too, combined with the ID. Sometimes you see, there are less chars/words between two IDs, this is my problem. In this case, only 2/3/4 words should be returned.

```
return
[1] DEV-1231 story is about a man.
[2] DEV-1232 is from
[3] DEV-1233 the USA. He is a
[4] DEV-1234 to Nepal. He
[5] DEV-1235 climbs a mountain. The mountain
[6] DEV-1236 He doesn't
[7] DEV-1237 go all the way down
```

In this example I though about up to 5 words which should be combined to the ID. Punctuation is possible in these 5 words.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `DEV-123[0-9]` try to match a "spaces + non-spaces" series of up to five occurrences (`(?:\s+\S+){0,5}`) but require the "non-spaces" don't match the `DEV-123[0-9]` pattern using negative lookahead:

```
DEV-123[0-9](?:\s+(?!DEV-123[0-9])\S+){0,5}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/AxtUkI/1

Comment: Supposed to be done in R. You haven't accounted for the fact that R needs extra escape characters. Plus you haven't done anything except offer a pattern. This problem probably needs `regmatches` and `regexpr`

Comment: Wow awesome, thanks a lot! The double escape in R is evident :) And your explanation is good for improving my skills! I managed it with `str_extract_all` and `unlist` as above mentioned

Comment: @42-: I put a pure regex for clarity. In a string literal of the target language the extra escape character should be added, you're right.